# Grub timeout 0 won't stop grub menu to come out

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I've originally had windows 10 only.
Then made it to dual boot win10 and ubuntu.
Now I removed win10 and only have ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

According to instruction, I've set timeout=0

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

But I still get grub screen every time I reboot.
I want to make my reboot faster, can anyone help please?

Comment: Are you seeing Windows 10 in the Grub menu?  Are you seeing a count down?  If so what is the countdown start number?

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal:

`sudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst`

Now change the line:   `## hiddenmenu` and delete `##`to leave it this way:

`hiddenmenu`

But you will not able to chose the old kernels, if there were any.

Comment: there is no such a file for me.

Comment: Try to add "nomodeset" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"` 


And then try 

`sudo update-grub` .

Learn about grub2 here [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2] , may can help you to resolve it.